# How can I improve app launch time(Pre main) time when I am using both objective-c as well as swift framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to use Multiple pod file in single Xcode project because I need to improve the pre-main time of app. As, I am using third party library some of them are in Objective C and some are in swift hence I am unable to convert them to the static framework because swift doesn't allow me to convert dynamic framework to static framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://techblog.izotope.com/2018/03/08/improving-your-ios-apps-launch-time/) article about how to improve app launch times in iOS?

It mentions about a `CocoaPods` plugin [Amimono](https://github.com/Ruenzuo/cocoapods-amimono) - which moves all dynamic frameworks symbols into the main executable, among few other techniques to improve app launch times (pre-main).